# how to go from windows 10 enterprise (unactivated) to windows 10 pro using windows 8.1 pro keys

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have windows 10 enterprise on a laptop. This is not activated and I want to change to windows 10 pro using my windows 8 pro keys.

TIA,

PS

Comment: Clean install W10 pro using the w8 keys.

Comment: How will get a copy of windows 10 pro iso? Is it something i can download? My MSDN account expired.

Comment: You need a W7,8.8.1 Pro install that is working, then use Microsoft tool to download the iso. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

You have to have upgraded from Windows 8 with the system already activated using those keys in order to activate the free Windows 10 Upgrade. It sounds as though you have done a fresh installation of Windows 10. Your best bet is to reinstall the original OS and do activate the product then proceed with the upgrade process.

Comment: The November update changed this, so that Windows 10 now accepts Windows 7 and 8 keys.  See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/activation-in-windows-10